# Deploying a custom built TensorFlow model within H2O

Tags: tensorflow, h2o

I am looking into using H2O to create a client-facing application from which they will be able to import data and run ML models on. As H2O only offers a limited number of models at the moment, is there any way to build custom models (an LSTM in TensorFlow, for example), import them into H2O where they can then be run just like any of H2O's included models?

It seems as though H2O's Deep Water was the nearest solution to this, but they have now discontinued its development.

In other words, is there any way to facilitate for different types of models that H2O does not support? (SVM, RNN, CNN, GAN, etc.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, deploying non-H2O-3 models within H2O-3 is unsupported.

Comment: That's unfortunate - why is this the case? I am very new to understanding how H2O works, so excuse my ignorance, but for H2O to run a model, couldn't the entire model essentially be a "black box" from H2O's point of view, where H2O just feeds the data into the model and retrieves the output? The majority of my work involves time-series problems, and I was excited with the idea of integrating H2O, but now it seems as though it is far too restricted with regards to time-series models.

Comment: The main reason is that H2O's models are built in-house and designed to run at scale and be distributed (note designing a model to be distributed is a feat in itself) - H2O isn't using someone else's model and viewing it as a "black box".

Comment: Makes perfect sense, I understand. Thank you